# TypeError: can't pickle _thread.RLock objects LSTM

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

When I tried to save my model, it happened. I'll appreciate if you could give me some help, thanks!. I have read some questions in StackOverflow or GitHub issuesbut can't find solution .

```
# add first layer with dropout

regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],1)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# add second layer

regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# add third layer

regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# add fourth layer

regressor.add(LSTM(units=50))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))

# the output layer

regressor.add(Dense(units=1))

# compiling the LSTM RNN network

regressor.compile(optimizer='rmsprop', loss='mean_squared_error')

# fit to the training set

regressor.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=32)

import pickle
filename = 'C:/Users/indore/Desktop/model.sav'
pickle.dump(regressor, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use `pickle` to save your model. Use in-built method `regressor.save('model.h5')`.